# Azure function HTTP Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

A question, could not find the answer. When I send a large array from a webpage to an Azure HTTP Trigger function does that function keep running until it is finished. Even when I would close the webpage before the function is finished processing my array or do I need to keep the webpage open and wait for the function to end?

Answer (score 0):

Once the webpage has finished with the request to the Azure Function the Function will do the processing of the array independently from the webpage. So yes, the function keeps running even when the webpage is closed. The request is solely a trigger to start the function.

If you do want to react on the client aborting the request see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202259/azure-functions-using-cancellation-token-with-http-trigger)